# Issue dividing routes per module with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

So I am writing an angular front end app for an enterprise client and my file structure is as such:

```
- App (root)
  - Assets
    - CSS
    - JS (plugins, libraries, etc)
    - Images
    - Fonts
  - Common
    - Header
      -header.html
    - Sidebar, etc
  - Modules
    - HR
      - HR.module.js (the module, for this module, yeah kinda confusing)
      - HR.routes.js (the routes for this module)
      - Employees
        - EmployeesController.js (the controller for this specific peice of thsis module)
        - EmployeesRepository.js (the factory/service for this app)
```

So far this has worked out alright (though tips are welcome) the issue i am running into is, if I have two modules (let's say HR and IT) then my main index page needs to utilize the routes from both, but you can only have one angular module per page. I could put all routes in a common app.js file, but that kind of messes with my seperation layout. Is there a solution to this? Or should I use a more elegant file sctructure?

Edit1 - routing

```
var hrModule = angular.module("hrModule", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/HR/Employees', { templateUrl: '/Modules/HR/Employees/Employees.html', controller: 'EmployeesController' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

Comment: "you can only have one angular module per page" - modules have little to do with "pages" (or, I think you mean, "views"). Modules are just a way to organize code.

Comment: @NewDev Sorry if i was confusing, I am making an SPA that has one index page, that utilizes multiple modules. But I can't utilize the routes from each of these modules on my index view, as I can't have more than one module per view.

Comment: This file structure is fine by the looks of it. You are separating by module rather than by function (like controller/view/etc). What you want to do is store your routes in a JSON file for each module, then have it read the JSONs based on which modules you're loading. This way you can read multiple JSON files and just group all the routes together when the app loads/is bootstrapped. So somewhere under Common, you would have your functionality which reads and adds new routes.

Comment: Also, can you provide some code which shows what your routes.js file looks like? (No need to share any secret data, just dummy data which shows what is happening would be fine)

Comment: @SoluableNonagon I added what I have at this exact moment for routing, currently it is happening in my `HR.Module.js` file, but I had planned on separating it

Comment: This is a bit tricky. You either need to consolidate all modules into one application, so that routing is done from one file (this is what I was suggesting earlier; and this would probably require a simple build system which would build routes based on json files included in the build). Or you have multiple ng-apps in your window, each with it's own view (something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/wpS8LVeEc5gVPS87n5AN?p=preview). This way would mean you need a routing system which hides views dependent on which module is showing, but you can hack away at this functionality.

Comment: The latter way would mean you need to guarantee no two modules repeat routes. otherwise you will have two views showing at once.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon So it seems the best solution is to simply have one common angular module and one routes file, but still split view up with their respective controllers/services, am I right? I may be thinking too .NET MVC about this

Comment: That would be correct. You only really want one application running at a time anyways, right?

Comment: @SoluableNonagon Yeah just one at a time, this should work perfectly thanks! Do you want to put that as an answer?

Comment: @Typhomism, answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.

You either need to:

1. Consolidate all modules into one application, so that routing is done from one file (this is what I was suggesting in the comments; and this would probably require a simple build system which would build routes based on json files included in the build).
2. Or you have multiple ng-apps in your window, each with it's own view (something like this: plnkr.co/edit/wpS8LVeEc5gVPS87n5AN?p=preview). This way would mean you need a routing system which hides views dependent on which module is showing, but you can hack away at this functionality.

If you are looking at creating a small build system which has routes defined in one file, I have a starter template here: [grunt-angular template](https://github.com/firebluetom/grunt-angular-template). You will need to hack it a little in the tasks if you want to grab multiple routes.

The readme should cover most of it, else feel free to message me.